# Plotting: How to space the xticks in a double y plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

After aggregation, i plotted the numbers but I am struggling to space the `xticks`.
I have tried different things for many hours but have not been successful. Please any help is more than welcome. Thank you

Here is the code and the output:

#### Aggregation

```
    tweet['Retweets']=pd.to_numeric(tweet['Retweets'])
    tweet['Favorites']=pd.to_numeric(tweet['Favorites'])
    sum_df = tweet.groupby(['Realdate'], as_index=False).agg({'Retweets': 
    'sum', 'Favorites': 'sum'})
    sum_df=sum_df.reset_index()
```

#### Plotting

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_xlabel('Dates')
ax1.set_ylabel('Favorites', color='b')
ax2.set_ylabel('Retweets', color='b')
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.tick_left()
sum_df['Favorites'].plot( kind='bar', color='y', ax=ax1) 
sum_df['Retweets'].plot( kind='line', marker='d', ax=ax2)
ax1.legend(loc=2) # is this the right thing to do to place legends?
ax2.legend(loc=1) # is this the right thing to do to place legends?
ax1.set_xticklabels(sum_df.Realdate.values, rotation=90)
plt.title('Sum of Daily "Likes" and Retweets Time Series')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts, that is the only solution i found

```
for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

which fairly spaces the xticks

[image]